# Need days in year month and days

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a table called Dates

```
Opendate        Closedate       
2015-07-09      NULL    
2017-01-25      NULL
```

I want to have the output as

```
Opendate    Workingperiod       
2015-07-09  1 years 8 months 20 days            
2017-01-25  0 years 1 months 3 days
```

We need to calculate the difference between opendate and today's date and in year month and days format.

have tried

```
SELECT Opendate,
   CAST(DATEDIFF(month,Opendate,GETDATE())/12 AS VARCHAR(5))+' year '+
   CAST(DATEDIFF(month,Opendate,GETDATE())%12 AS VARCHAR(5)) +' month '+
   CAST(DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,Opendate,GETDATE()),Opendate),GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(5))+' days ' AS Workingperiod
FROM Dates
```

Output:-

```
Opendate    Workingperiod     
2015-07-09  1 year 8 month -8 days     
2017-01-25  0 year 2 month -24 days
```

I am getting days in negative, can someone tell what is wrong in it.

Comment: Are you assuming 30 day months or actual?

Comment: actual days I am assuming, but even if its 30 still I can manage

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @opendate datetime, @date datetime, @years int, @months int, @days int
SELECT @opendate = '2015-07-09'
SELECT @date = @opendate
SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(YYYY, @date, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@opendate) > MONTH(GETDATE())) 
 OR (MONTH(@opendate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(@opendate) > DAY(GETDATE())) 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
SELECT @date = DATEADD(YYYY, @years, @date)
SELECT @months = DATEDIFF(MONTH, @date, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN DAY(@opendate) > DAY(GETDATE()) 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
SELECT @date = DATEADD(MONTH, @months, @date)  
SELECT @days = DATEDIFF(DAY, @date, GETDATE()) 
SELECT @years AS 'YEARS', @months AS 'MONTHS', @days  AS 'DAYS'
```

FIRST ENTRY  (2015-07-09)

[image: FIRST]

SECOND ENTRY (2017-01-25)

[image: SECOND]